# camel spring DSL redelivery for ever

Tags: exception, apache-camel

HI created a simple Camel Spring application to consume an XSL file .
My camel context file is shown below ,the route is composed by InitProcessor, ExcelProcessor and FinalProcessor.
The camel route go ahead well but at the final processor I call a web service and obtain a Soap Fault , then camel re delivery payload for ever  , why ? 
It seam no matter about onException declaration and then no call to my custom Exception processor (processorEx) , why ?

thanks

camel-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:config/conf.properties</value>

            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <camelContext id="camel"  trace="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" >

        <onException>
                <exception>org.savino.hb.dataprovider.DataProviderException</exception>
            <!--
                <handled>
                    <constant>true</constant>
                </handled>
                -->
                <!--log loggingLevel="ERROR" message="HEY I GOT AN EXCEPTION" /--> 
                <!--to uri="log:org.savino.hb.dataprovider?level=DEBUG"/-->
                <to uri="processorEx"/>
                <to uri="file:C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/HB_DATA/mov_fail?fileName=${header.X_UID}"/>
                <process ref="processorEx"/>
            </onException>


        <route>
            <from uri="file:C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/HB_DATA/mov?delay=1000&amp;move=../mov_done&amp;moveFailed=../mov_fail"/>
            <process ref="processor"/>
            <log message="Header: $simple{in.headers[X_FILENAME]}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="header-test" />
             <to uri="log:com.mycompany.order?level=DEBUG"/>
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${in.header.X_CARD} == true</simple>
                    <to uri="bean:excelCard"/>
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <to uri="bean:excelMov"/>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
            <to uri="bean:finalProcessor"/>

            <!--process ref="processor"/-->


        </route>

    </camelContext>
    <bean name="dataProcessor" class="org.savino.hb.dataprovider.ws.WSDataProcessor"/>
    <bean name="excelMov" class="org.savino.hb.dataprovider.ExcelTransformer">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="9"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="1"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="2"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="3"/>
        <constructor-arg index="4" value="4"/>
        <constructor-arg index="5" value="5"/>
        <constructor-arg index="6" value="6"/>
    </bean>
    <bean name="excelCard" class="org.savino.hb.dataprovider.ExcelTransformer">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="8"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="1"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" value="2"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3" value="0"/>
        <constructor-arg index="4" value="6"/>
        <constructor-arg index="5" value="3"/>
        <constructor-arg index="6" value="0"/>
    </bean>
    <bean name="processor" class="org.savino.hb.dataprovider.Processor"/>
    <bean name="finalProcessor" class="org.savino.hb.dataprovider.FinalProcessor"/>
    <bean name="processorEx" class="org.savino.hb.dataprovider.ProcessorEx"/>

</beans>
```

ProcessorEx that I want to be executed when the FinalProcessor get Exception

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.savino.hb.dataprovider;


import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;




/**
 *
 * @author f.savino
 */
public class ProcessorEx implements org.apache.camel.Processor{
    private static final Logger logger =LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessorEx.class);

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Exception ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class);
        String uid = exchange.getIn().getHeader("X_UID").toString();
        if (ex== null)
            logger.warn(uid+"::Exception NULL");
        else if (ex instanceof DataProviderException)
            logger.error(uid+"::"+ex.toString(),ex);
        else 
            logger.error(uid+"::Exception",ex);
    }

}
```

The FinalProcessor

```
public class FinalProcessor implements org.apache.camel.Processor{

    @Autowired
    DataProcessor dataProcessor;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        List<Item> m = (List<Item>) exchange.getIn().getBody();
        String cc = exchange.getIn().getHeader("X_CC").toString();
        String periodo = exchange.getIn().getHeader("X_PERIODO").toString();
        boolean card = Boolean.valueOf(exchange.getIn().getHeader("X_CARD").toString());
        DataContainer data = new DataContainer();

        data.setCc(cc);
        data.setCard(card);
        data.setPeriodo(periodo);
        data.setItems(m);

            ReplyContainer reply = dataProcessor.processMov(data);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching that specific exception, can you try catching all exceptions by updating onException block to below,

```
<onException redeliveryPolicyRef="myRedelivery">
    <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
```

and you can declare myRedelivery as

```
<redeliveryPolicyProfile id="myRedelivery" redeliveryDelay="{{redeliverydelayvalue}}" maximumRedeliveries="{{maxredeliveryvalue}}"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately ,any change with this trick . I suppose my problem is in the last processor , the FinalProcessor, where I get the exception , maybe the exception is not "heard" by Camel ? I am meaning ,maybe my Exception is interpreted by Came l as a Recoverable Exception and then default policy try to re delivery the message ? Anyway I am adding  the FinalProcessor to initial issue

Comment: Currently your code is only trying to capture exeption "org.savino.hb.dataprovider.DataProviderException" and that might not be the exception thats actually thrown. Thats why I recommended changing it to "java.lang.Exception" so that all exceptions will be caught.